# I want to display images when i click on it

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot display images when I click on the target. I have nine images and I need to display them as soon as I click on images.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-modale');

const modaleEquipement = document.querySelector('.bloc-modale');

const fermetureModale = document.querySelector('.fermeture-modale');

const imgIndex = document.querySelector('.bloc-modale img');


btns.forEach(btn => {

    btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        imgIndex.src = `ressources/img${e.target.getAttribute('data-index')}-equip.jpg`;
        modaleEquipement.classList.add('active-modale');

    });

});
```

```html
<button type="button" data-index="1" class="btn-modale"></button> 
<button type="button" data-index="2" class="btn-modale"></button>
<button type="button" data-index="3" class="btn-modale"></button>
<button type="button" data-index="4" class="btn-modale"></button>
<button type="button" data-index="5" class="btn-modale"></button>
<button type="button" data-index="6" class="btn-modale"></button>
<button type="button" data-index="7" class="btn-modale"></button>
<button type="button" data-index="8" class="btn-modale"></button>
<button type="button" data-index="9" class="btn-modale"></button>
```

Comment: could you also show us the html? It would be helpful when trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: @SuspenseFallback ok,

Comment: does bloc-modale have another class called 'img' or is 'img' inside bloc-modale? if it is, you have to add a dot before 'img' - document.querySelector('.bloc-modale .img')